# Display table inside row of table when generate PDF using dompdf

Tags: php, html, dompdf

maybe any some one can help me to solve my problem. In my case I want to display a table base on result of another query. I display the result of query to a row of table too. This is what I mind:

[image]

This is what I've done, but the result was messed up especially when I generate to PDF using dompdf. **The result show that first row of table based on query data1/data2 always show beside header table (th1/th2)**.

```
    echo "<table>";

    foreach($rows as $row){

        $sql2 = "select * from table A where iddata =".$row[iddata];
        echo "
        <tr><td>$row['data1']</td></tr>
        <tr>
           <td>
              <table>
                 <thead>
                      <tr>
                           <td>th1</td>
                           <td>th2</td>
                      </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>";

                 $rows2 = $this->db->query($sql2)->result_array();
                 foreach($rows2 as $row2){
                      echo "
                      <tr>
                         <td>".$row2['val1']."</td>
                         <td>".$row2['val1']."</td>
                      </tr>";
                 }
                 echo "</tbody>
              </table>
           </td>
        </tr>
    ";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Maybe some one can explain how to solve that. Thanks

Comment: your missing a lot of stuff, like executing the query, etc.  Right now you just have a string `$sql2` that contains SQL.  I don't even know what this is `$rows2 = query using $sql2;` not any PHP I ever seen, an I seen a lot of PHP>

Comment: please create string for table before any output

Comment: Thanks all, can some one make an example please? I was update my code.